# Drop Down Nav List

Tags: html, css, nav

I want my drop down list top apear inline aswell as in the same place. So if you over over each list it will just change the text. http://868rcacs.ca/test.php

Right Now I have the drop down list working. But when you hover over Admin the list will apear  right below it and not to the far left. Is there a way to fix this without using individual classes or id's?

Comment: do you want all links to below the main links. like this http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/pNAkf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following styles:

```
nav{
position:relative;
}

nav li ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
}
```

This ensures that your layout doesn't break and you get what you want. Don't forget to thank me if this works ;-) Just kidding!

Comment: Thanks!! Works like a charm. Wasn't sure if anyone knew what I meant. haha